# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SFSWhale'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

getting error while importing library in google colaboratory.
This is the code that i tried . Also I haven't installed anythiing before. It seem SFSWhale is not there in colab libraries.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import librosa
from SFSWhale import jfs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dense, InputLayer, BatchNormalization, Dropout #defining CONV2d classes
from keras.layers import LSTM #defining LSTM class
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Lambda
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import pickle
from keras.layers import Bidirectional, GRU #defining extension GRU and bidirectional
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score 
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-6fe00084003e> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import librosa
----> 5 from SFSWhale import jfs
      6 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
      7 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SFSWhale'
```

what should i install to support above imports?

Comment: what is SFSWhale module? `sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector` ??